# Java. Server don't send proper HTML

Tags: java, html, cookies

I wrote little app in Java but it don't serv HTML properly.
Problem occurs when method checkCookies return false. Normally an "else" clause should be executed but this doesn't happen. Some intresting thing -  the app is going 3 times from start of handle() method to first condition (counter is increasing). I don't know how to repair it. If i got a cookie with name "Login" or  i manually modify method to always return true it's working good.
Main file:
Loginpage.java

```
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

public class Loginpage {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception{
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);
        server.createContext("/form", new Form());
        server.setExecutor(null);
        server.start();
    }
}
```

Form.java

```
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.HttpCookie;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Form implements HttpHandler {
int counter = 0;

@Override
public void handle(HttpExchange httpExchange) throws IOException {
    counter++;
    System.out.println(counter);
    List<String> cookies = httpExchange.getRequestHeaders().get("Cookie");
    HttpCookie cookie;
    String response = "<html><body>system</body></html>";
    String method = httpExchange.getRequestMethod();
    if (checkCookies(cookies)) {
        response = "<html><body> Hello! </body></html>";
    } else {
        if (method.equals("GET")) {
            response = "<html><body><form method='post'>" +
                    "<input type='text' name='username'><br>" +
                    "<input type='password' name='pass'><br>" +
                    "<input type='submit' value='login'<br>" +
                    "</form></body></html>";
        } else if (method.equals("POST")) {
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(httpExchange.getRequestBody(), "utf-8");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String formData = br.readLine();
            Map data = parseFormData(formData);
            if (checkData(data)) {
                cookie = new HttpCookie("Login", String.valueOf(counter + (counter * 12)));
                httpExchange.getResponseHeaders().add("Set-Cookie", cookie.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    httpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
    OutputStream os = httpExchange.getResponseBody();
    os.write(response.getBytes());
    os.close();
}

private boolean checkCookies(List<String> cookies) {
    boolean isValid = false;
    for (String s : cookies) {
        System.out.println(s);
        if (s.matches("Login.*")) {
            isValid = true;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(isValid);
    return isValid;
}

private boolean checkData(Map<String, String> data) {
    DAO dao = new DAO();
    String username = data.get("username");
    System.out.println(username);

    String password = data.get("pass");
    System.out.println(password);
    if (dao.checkData(username, password)) {
        return true;
    } else return false;

}

private static Map<String, String> parseFormData(String formData) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    String[] pairs = formData.split("&");
    for (String pair : pairs) {
        String[] keyValue = pair.split("=");
        String value = new URLDecoder().decode(keyValue[1], "UTF-8");
        map.put(keyValue[0], value);
    }
    return map;
}
}
```

**UPDATE**
I found the cause of my problem. If I send a empty *List* to the *checkCookies()* method the program "hangs". Adding the condition

```
 if (cookies == null) return false;
```

in checkCookies() method solved the problem but I do not know why it was not just return false before fix.
Can anyone explain it?

Comment: It wasn't an empty list - it was a `null` reference. Hence you got a `NullPointerException` and your code aborted. Look in the console or the log files to find the exception.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt in console i don't have any Exception. Just counter increases 3 times and that's all. I also check log and nothing - again. Program still running but don't go to "next step".